# Should i release objects that i get from dictionary on Mac?

Tags: macos, dictionary, refs

ie:

```
boolRef = (CFBooleanRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(descriptionDictionary, kDADiskDescriptionMediaRemovableKey);
if (boolRef) {
    CFRelease(boolRef); // do i need this code?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First read the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i). The answer is no, because of the Create Rule. `CFDictionaryGetValue()` does not include the words "Create" or "Copy."

Note that `CFRelease()` in this case is not just unneeded, it is incorrect and will lead to an over-release crash.

Comment: There are precious few cases where releasing *is* optional. In almost every case, either you need to do it or you need to *not* do it.

Comment: Thank you. I've read this before asking, but in the example i used they were released, so i was not sure.